# jest projects different setupfiles for each project not working

Tags: config, project, jestjs

My file structure is something like:

```
Product/
    |- httpdocs/
        |- jest.config.js
        |- modules/
            |- modules1/
                |- jest.config.js
            |- modules2/
                |- jest.config.js
            |- modules3/
                |- jest.config.js
```

In each `jest.config.js` under the modules I have some configuration for that specific module like: `setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/testHelpers/setup.js']`.

In my top `jest.config.js` (under `httpdocs`) I have defined my different projects:

```
projects: [
    '<rootDir>/modules/module1',
    '<rootDir>/modules/module2',
    '<rootDir>/modules/module3'
]
```

When I run `jest` under `httpdocs`, the tests fail because the setupfiles (and other configuration) are ignored inside my `module/jest.config.js` files.

When I run `jest` under `module1`, all the tests succeed

Am I doing something wrong or does the option `projects` not work like this?

## -------- EDIT 1 --------

So I restructered my configs like @cimenx suggested.

```
Product/
    |- jest.config.js
    |- httpdocs/
        |- modules/
            |- modules1/
                |- foo/
                    |- bar/
                        |- foobar.js
                        |- foobar.test.js
            |- modules2/
                |- ...
```

my jest.config.js file looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
  rootDir: './httpdocs/modules',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/', '/smsc/'],
  projects: [
    {
      displayName: 'module1',
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/module1/*.test.js']
    },
    {
      displayName: 'module2',
      testMatch: ['<rootDir>/module2/*.test.js']
    }
  ]
};
```

At the moment the issue is that jest cannot find any tests inside my modules.

## -------- SOLUTION --------

While I was writing my **EDIT 1**, I tried some other configs...
Apparently my `<rootDir>` is always the directory where my `jest.config.js` file is in.

The solution for me was to write the whole path from the config file to the modules without the option `rootDir: './some/path'`

```
module.exports = {
    projects: [
        {
          displayName: 'module1',
          testMatch: ['<rootDir>/httpdocs/modules/module1/**/*.test.js']
        },
        {
          displayName: 'module2',
          testMatch: ['<rootDir>/httpdocs/modules/module2/**/*.test.js']
        }
    ]
};
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably you should remove all `jest.config.js` on each modules and rewrite the `Product/httpdocs/jest.config.js` to be something like this:

```
module.exports = {
    projects: [
        {
            displayName: "modules1",
            setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/modules/modules1/jest.setup.js',
            /*
               Jest config that is specific for modules1
            */
            testMatch: ["<rootDir>/modules/modules1/*.spec.js"],
        },
        {
            displayName: "modules2",
            setupTestFrameworkScriptFile: '<rootDir>/modules/modules2/jest.setup.js',
            /*
              Jest config that is specific for modules2
            */
            testMatch: ["<rootDir>/modules/modules2/*.spec.js"]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but now when I run `jest` it cannot find any tests anymore. Have tried a dozen different configs but no config seem to find anything.

When I remove the option `projects`, and set the config of one project out of the option `projects` it works for that one project.

When I try to put it again in the option `projects` (with the other projects also) it doesn't work.

Comment: Strange, that's setup is working fine for me. Could you edit your question and share step-by-step what you are doing now? Also, just want to make sure, what is the filename of your test files?